# How can we study $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi_t(x)dx$, when $\lim$ and $\int$ do not commute?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, integration, measure-theory

I am dealing with the problem of studying
$$\mathcal{I}= \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi_t(x)dx$$
In my problem $\psi_t(x)$ is of the form $f_t(x)\mathbf{1}_{x>t}$. Moreover, $f_t(x)=\frac{g(x)}{g(t)}\varphi(t-x+k)$ where $g>
0$ is the probability density function of a continuous unbounded support random variable and $\varphi$ is the probability density function of a standard normal ($k$ being a constant).

It is clear that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\psi_t(x)$ is pointwise $0$. As a consequence, whenever I can bound $|\psi_t(x)|$ by an integrable function it's easy to conclude $\mathcal{I}=0$ by dominated convergence theorem. The ratio appearing in the integrand is always smaller than one (at least when $g$ is eventually decreasing) but, since the $f$ factor translates, it is difficult to find the desired bound.

Actually, depending on shape of $g$, this may not be possible.Indeed, numerical simulation suggest that, for many interesting choices of $g$, we have $\mathcal{I}\neq 0$. In these cases, it seems that it *must not be possible* to exchange integral and limit.

How to proceed ?

**EDIT** It is useful to notice that by de l'hospital $$-\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{g'(t)}{g(t)}=\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{g(t)}{1-G(t)}$$ which appears in the calculations below.

Here [Computation of $ \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_t^\infty\frac{g(x)}{\sigma g(t)}f(\frac{t-x}{\sigma}+k)dx$ with $g$ and $\varphi$ density functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499669/computation-of-lim-t-to-infty-int-t-infty-fracgx-sigma-gtf-fract) I attempt a probably flawed calculation.

Comment: I would shift to get $$\int_0^\infty \frac{g(x+t)}{g(t)} \varphi(k-x) dx$$ and then pray that I have some useful information on the first fraction. Maybe you can include what kind of information you would have apriori about $g$. In general I'd say the night is dark and full of pathologies.

Comment: Can you give an explicit example of the $g$ you can work with? Perhaps you can provide the simplest possible example, and we can try and generalize.

Comment: Monotonic decreasing isn't sufficient to make $\mathcal{I} = 0$ -- I assumed as much in my answer and came up short. You need to have the derivative of the pdf become negative at an increasing rate (concave function) but that leads to a contradiction since the pdf must remain positive over entire real line.

Comment: as @SarveshRavichandranIyer said, can you provide an example pdf where $\mathcal{I} = 0$?

Comment: @ Bey Numerically it goes to 0 with a Weibull with shape parameter >1

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta -- you are correct :) I've updated my answer -- my contradiction was not correct -- I was using average derivative vs the more subtle condition on $g(x)/g'(x)$.

Comment: @Bey Thanks a lot for the incredible work, at least now I have a sufficient condition for $I=0$. Indeed your proof also bounds the integral when $g(x)/g'(x)$ is finite at the limit! The remaining case is when it goes to infinity, but I think it would be another nightmare.

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta You could ask a separate question regarding that. It might be tractable for specific situations. +1

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer this problem is really haunting haunting me! Here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499669/computation-of-lim-t-to-infty-int-t-infty-fracgx-sigma-gtf-fract   I try another approach, which leads to a close form, but probably a wrong one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my go at this -- Severin anticipated my approach a bit.

One technical issue here is that $g$ is a valid pdf as long as $g>0$ *almost everywhere* (i.e., even if there is a subset  $X$ of Lebesgue measure $0$ where $g(x)=0\;\; \forall x \in X$).

Let's ignore that case and say that $g(x)>0 \;\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Another edge case to ignore is where there exists a countable, increasing sequence $x_i$ such that $g(x_i)$ forms a divergent sequence. This will not matter in the integral but will complicate the limit proofs. See comments for some examples from others.

---

Expanding $\psi_i(x)$ to the full form (for clarity):

$$\psi_t(x) = \left[\frac{g(x)}{g(t)}\varphi(t-x+k)\right]\mathbf{1}_{x>t}$$

**EDIT**: As shown in the comments below, I cannot support the below solely based on $g \in L_1$, hence I will move it to an assumption:

**Assume** that $g$ eventually becomes a monotonically decreasing function bounded below by 0:
$$(*)\;\;\lim_{x\to -\infty} g(x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} g(x)= 0$$

So we have:

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)\mathbf{1}_{x>t} dx = 0$$

For any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we also know

$$0 < \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi_t(x)dx \; < \infty $$

Looking at the way you've defined $\psi_t(x)$, we see that the normal factor $\varphi$ translates along with the region where $\mathbf{1}_{x>t}$ is positive, so for all intents and purposes we can recast this by letting $\delta:= x-t$ (i.e., the distance into the non-zero part of the integral):

$$Q_t := \int_{0}^\infty \frac{g(t+\delta)}{g(t)}\varphi(k-\delta)d\delta$$

We can see that for every $t$, $Q_t$ is basically an integral of a scaled and truncated version of $g$ multiplied by a gaussian with mean that is always located $k$ units to the right of $t$.

Now we can invoke $(*)$ to get what we need:

$$(*) \implies \forall t: \exists z_t>t: g(x) < g(t) \;\;\forall x>z_t$$

This means that we can decompose $Q_t$ into two parts (with $\Delta_t:=z_t-t$):

$$Q_t = \int_0^{\Delta_t} \frac{g(t+\delta)}{g(t)}\varphi(k-\delta)d\delta + \int_{\Delta_t}^{\infty} \frac{g(t+\delta)}{g(t)}\varphi(k-\delta)d\delta$$

Let's assume that that $\lim_{t\to \infty} \Delta_t =0$, which basically says that $g(x) \to h(x)$ where $h'(x) < 0\; \forall x$ is a monotonically decreasing function.

The first term is easy to evaluate now:

$$ \lim_{t\to \infty} \Delta_t = 0 \implies \int_0^{\Delta_t} \frac{g(t+\delta)}{g(t)}\varphi(k-\delta)d\delta \to \int_0^{0} \frac{g(t+\delta)}{g(t)}\varphi(k-\delta)d\delta = 0$$

But the second term becomes troublesome:

$$ 0 \leq \lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{\Delta_t}^{\infty} \frac{g(t+\delta)}{g(t)}\varphi(k-\delta)d\delta \leq \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{\Delta_t}^{\infty} \varphi(k-\delta)d\delta = \lim_{t\to \infty}-\Phi(k-t)+ \Phi(k-\Delta_t) = \frac{1}{2}$$

So you need a stronger condition than simply it eventually becoming monotonically decreasing.

Another bound we can examine is:

$$0 \leq \int_{\Delta_t}^{\infty} \frac{g(t+\delta)}{g(t)}\varphi(k-\delta)d\delta < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{\Delta_t}^{\infty} \frac{g(t+\delta)}{g(t)}d\delta$$

Pulling out the denominator we get:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}g(t)} \int_{\Delta_t}^{\infty} g(t+\delta)d\delta = \frac{1-F_g(t+\Delta_t)}{\sqrt{2 \pi}g(t)} $$

Taking the limit we have an indeterminate form:

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1-F_g(t+\Delta_t)}{\sqrt{2 \pi}g(t)} = \frac{0}{0}$$

Using L'Hospital's rule, we get:

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1-F_g(t+\Delta_t)}{\sqrt{2 \pi}g(t)} = \frac{-g(t+\Delta_t)}{\sqrt{2 \pi}g'(t)}$$

So here we get a sufficient condition, assuming $\Delta_t = 0$ without loss of generality (since if $\Delta_t$ is any increasing function of $t$ it just pushes $g$ towards its limit even faster).

$$ -g(t) = o(g'(t)) \implies \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{-g(t+\Delta_t)}{\sqrt{2 \pi}g'(t)} = 0$$

So absolute rate of decrease of $g$ must become much larger than $g$ as $t\to\infty$

What kind of functions satisfy this? It can't be the exponential:

$$g(x) \propto e^{-x} \implies \frac{-g(x)}{g'(x)} = 1$$

**EDIT**: I stand corrected! The Weibull with shape > 1 does indeed satisfy the above condition and so is a valid $g$ for this problem (as found numerically by OP). If we let scale param be 1 (without loss of generality), we get these results:

$$ \frac{-g(x)}{g'(x)}=\frac{-k x^{k - 1} e^{-x^k}}{(-ke^{-x^k}) x^{k - 2}(k(x^k - 1) + 1)} = \frac{ x}{kx^k + 1-k}$$

$$k \in (0,1) \implies \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{ x}{kx^k + 1-k}= \infty$$

$$k = 1 \implies \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{ x}{kx^k + 1-k}=1$$

$$k > 1 \implies \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{ x}{kx^k + 1-k}=0$$

Comment: Statement $(\ast)$ doesn’t imply: “now we can invoke $(\ast)$ to get what we need” (I also think there is a typo there) - $g$ is positive and has limit zero at infinity, but we can’t necessarily suppose that this limit is monotonically obtained

Comment: @FShrike I was just using the definition of a limit, not assuming its monotonic — I do assume monotonic later. All I'm saying is that if $g \to 0$ then at some point $g(x)$ drops below $g(t)$ and stays below it per def. of a limit.

Comment: @FShrike -- you are correct I had a typo -- fixed it so hopefully makes more sense

Comment: I see it now. I originally read it as you’d written “$g(x)<g(z_t)\forall x>z_t$ which caused alarm

Comment: Maybe you could remark that $(*)$ really is an assumption you are making (it does not follow from the $L^1$ condition).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven so there are examples of positive functions in L1 that have infinite support and dont tend to 0? Happy to make this an assumption but I thought it followed from the definition of a pdf

Comment: What about a normalized version of $$e^{-x^2} + \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n^3} 1_{[n;n+1/n]}(x).$$ You will not go to zero as you have the bumps (you can also make this smooth if you want to).

Comment: @Severin Svhraven Thanks to both for the useful answer and comments! You already helped me a lot but see the edit for additional info, if you like

Comment: @SeverinSchraven isn't this function (let's call it $f(x)$) bounded above by $g(x) = e^{-x^2} + \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor^3}$ and from below by $0$? In that case, $0\leq  f(x) \leq g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = 0$ So by squeeze theorem, the limit of $f$ must be zero? Perhaps you were thinking I was assuming the *derivative* goes to zero? In that case I agree there are many counterexamples, such as the one you gave.

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta -- see above -- looks like indeed the weibull is a valid function for $g$! My "proof" using the average value of the derivative wasn't correct -- we only need the tangent to drop slower than the value of the function, but that is a second-derivative condition, not the condition I tried to use.

Comment: About positive functions in $L^1$ with infinite support that do not tend to zero, take any sequence of increasingly tall triangles centered at points going to infinity whose width shrinks fast enough and sum them to get an $f$ with infinite support and finite $L^1$ norm such that $\limsup_{|x|\to\infty}f(x) = \infty$.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz -- nice -- yes -- that does the trick -- so $L_1$ isn't sufficient and I will mark this as an assumption.

Comment: @Bey I am sorry, I should have written $1_{[n;n+1/n^2]}$. Indeed, what I wrote above does go to zero.