# Computation of $ \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_t^\infty\frac{g(x)}{\sigma g(t)}f(\frac{t-x}{\sigma}+k)dx$ with $g$ and $\varphi$ density functions.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, integration, measure-theory

In [How can we study $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi_t(x)dx$, when $\lim$ and $\int$ do not commute?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498522/how-can-we-study-lim-t-to-infty-int-mathbbr-psi-txdx-when-lim-an) I was wondering about general techniques to evaluate limits of integral functions when theorems exchanging $\int$ and $\lim$ do not apply. As I learned there, thanks to the valuable effort of many incredibly nice users, in general we cannot say much. Here I propose an explicit computation for this particular case.
Let $f$ be the density funnction of a standard normal and restrict to $g$ continuous, always positive, unbounded support and eventually monotonically decreasing. Let $I$ be the limit to study. @Bey smartly proved (for $\sigma=1$, but the proof should generalize) that if:
$$\rho=-\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{g'(t)}{g(t)}=\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{g(t)}{1-G(t)}$$
is $\infty$ (equivalently, the inverse is $0$) then $\mathcal{I}=0$ and if it is finite, $\mathcal{I}<C$, where $C$ is a constant. A different take on the problem may be as follows.
Oberve that
$$I=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{g(t)}\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma }f\left( \frac{t-x }{\sigma }%
+k\right) g(\theta )dx$$,changing variable as $
p=G(x)$, $dp=g(x)dx$,  rewrites as
$$I=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{g(t)}\int_{G(t)}^{1}%
\frac{1}{\sigma }f\left( \frac{t-G^{-1}(p)}{\sigma }+k\right)
dp$$
The limit is of the  $\frac{0}{0}$ form. Applying de l'Hopital:
$$I=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{g^{\prime }(t)}\underbrace{%
\left[ \int_{G(t)}^{1}\frac{1}{\sigma }f\left( \frac{%
t-G^{-1}(p)}{\sigma }+k\right) dp\right] ^{\prime }}_{H}$$
Via Leibniz integral rule:
$$H=-\left[\frac{1}{\sigma}\right]\left[g(t)f\left( k\right) +\int_{G(t)}^{1}\frac{1}{\sigma }f^{\prime }\left( \frac{t-G^{-1}(p)}{\sigma }%
+k\right) \frac{1}{g\left( G^{-1}(p)\right) }dp\right]$$
Changing variable in the right integral as $x =G^{-1}(p)$, $dx =%
\frac{1}{g\left( G^{-1}(p)\right) }dp$:
$$H=\left[ -\frac{1}{\sigma }\right] \left[ g(t)f\left( k\right)
+\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma }f^{\prime }\left( \frac{t-x }{%
\sigma }+k\right) dx \right]$$
A primitive of the right integrand is: $-f\left( \frac{t-x }{\sigma }%
+k\right) $, so that evaluating and rearranging terms:
$$H=\lim_{s\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{\sigma }\right] \left[f\left( \frac{t-s}{\sigma }%
+k\right)-f\left(
k\right) -g(t)f\left(
k\right) \right]=\frac{-f(k)[1+g(t)]}{\sigma}$$
as pointed out in the comments. Substituting back inside $I$:
$$I=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\left[-\frac{1}{\sigma}\right]\left[\frac{f(k)(1+g(t))}{g'(t)}\right]=+\infty$$

Which is a contradiction with what found in the previous question.  There must be an error in my calculations, but I think the approach can be revealing.

Any help would be most welcome!

Comment: I'll see when I can take a look at this question. Perhaps others may be quicker than me, but if I can then I will try to be fairly comprehensive in my approach.

Comment: What is $\theta$? Also, $H=\lim_{s\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{\sigma }\right] \left[f\left( \frac{t-s}{\sigma}
+k\right)-f\left(k\right) -g(t)f\left(k\right) \right] = \left[\frac{1}{\sigma }\right] \left[0-f\left(k\right) -g(t)f\left(k\right) \right] = \frac{-f\left(k\right)[1+g(t)]}{\sigma }$, so no need for double limit?

Comment: @Bey Yeah you are right, there should be no problems, actually I was hoping there was some problem at that level to prevent the contradiction. $\theta$ is a typo, should be $x$! I edited everything. I am convinced that your proof is right in the other post, so I must be missing something here.